# How to inject Java applet's getGraphics() method?

Tags: java

First what I want to say is that this is my favorite help site for Java. (and other languages)
Now my question is, I want to take a screenshot of a Java applet.
I have load the applet via the java.net.URLClassLoader and added it to my JFrame.
I can see it in my JFrame but I want to render it to a screenshot.
The solution for NORMAL applets is mentioned here: [Taking a "screenshot" of a java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395002/taking-a-screenshot-of-a-java-applet)
But this Applet doesn't use the paint nor update method, instead it uses the getGraphics() method.
I have already injected the AppletStub so the applets thinks he is on his own website.
But how can I inject the applet its getGraphics() method to render it to a screenshot?

BTW, this is my code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    final String s = e.getActionCommand();
    if (s.equals("Screenshot")) {
        final BufferedImage offScreen = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Loader.getApplet().update(offScreen.createGraphics());
        try {
            ImageIO.write(offScreen, "PNG", new File("C:/Users/Mitchell/Pictures/screenshot.png"));
        } catch (Exception ex) {  }
    }
}
```

All it creates is a black 800x600 png image (the empty BufferedImage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get away with it, create a subclass of the `Applet` in question, and override `getGraphics()` such that it will return your `Graphics` object, then use the subclass instead of the original.

Comment: So you mean like: public class GraphicsInjector extends Applet?

Comment: I mean `GraphicsInjector extends X`, where `X` is the applet you're trying to work with.

Comment: I already came up with that, but the Applet is a variable... :P